# Spectral theorem and positive definite inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, spectral-theory

In this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) the spectral theorem for finite dimension case, the **positive definiteness of inner product** is assumed. However in the following proof of spectral theorem, it seems to me that this condition is only used in proving the eigenvalues are real.

> $\lambda_1\langle{e_1},{e_1}\rangle = \langle A(e_1),e_1\rangle=\langle e_1,A(e_1)\rangle=\bar{\lambda}\langle{e_1},{e_1}\rangle$

**Positive definiteness of inner product** implies $\langle{e_1},{e_1}\rangle\neq0$ then $\lambda_1=\bar{\lambda}$.

It seems to me the rest of the proof dose not use positive definiteness of inner product.

I wonder if positive definiteness is just a sufficient condition for spectral theorem or not.

Any help would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found where we need the definiteness.

In the proof of spectral theorem we use the fact that the *orthogonal complement* of an eigenvector $\mathrm{w}$ is an invariant subspace of the symmetry operator.

Here is the point :
We need definiteness to assert that the linear space $V$ is indeed an direct sum $V=\mathrm{w}\bigoplus \mathrm{w}^{\perp}$ so as to proceed our proof by induction.

For example, let $V=\mathbf{C}^2$ with $\langle X,Y\rangle=x_1y_1-x_2y_2$. The scalar product is indefinite. Now suppose the symmetry operator $A$ have an eigenvector $\mathrm{w} =(1,i)$, then $\mathrm{w}^{\perp}=\mathrm{w}$. We cannot have an orthogonal basis consists of eigenvectors for this case.